# Is 'no_found_rows' a silver bullet for WP_Query optimization when getting all posts of a certain type?

Tags: wp-query

I'm running a query (200-300 posts), while this might not be for a lot of people / hosts, I just want to optimize wherever I can, given the fact that a lot of things happen when running that particular script, and so, my motivation is optimization.

My query is exactly:

```
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby' => 'ASC',
        'post__in' => $post_ids
    ];

    $headers = new \WP_Query( $args );
```

So I'm asking the database to just give me everything that matches these IDs. But I don't need any meta information, no paging information, no counting of the posts, nothing, just the raw posts, so I was thinking of adding `no_found_rows => true` to the query.

While this clearly speeds things up, if I think of all the `WP_Query` I wrote through my system, I rarely need to know pagination or their count.

**Or don't I?** When there's no pagination, how does the system know to go to the next "batch"?

In other, simpler words: is `no_found_rows => true` a must-have when querying big  lists of posts where you just need to know about all the posts in a given query?

Comment: note that there are lots of performance cardinal sins in using `WP_Query` that have nothing to do with pagination, a lot of the reasoning behind upper limits of 100 is that more means an increase in page generation times, and memory consumption. It's simply more efficient to do smaller queries. If pagination itself is a serious concern for performance though, I would be concerned as that's unusual. Also, it's a protection against resource exhaustion attacks, which could happen with unlimited post retrieval

Comment: @TomJNowell Interesting, do you have any writeups / articles on this? Everywhere I go, there's always a few dozen WP_Queries in a system but no one talks about their performance, what the cons / pros are.

Comment: can you be more specific? I would note that this stack is a Q&A site, but not a discussion forum, so you need to be able to phrase your question such that I can write an answer that's considered canonically correct for any person with the same question, but it sounds like you're wanting a discussion, and one with wider scope

Comment: @TomJNowell I think my question was both precise and borad. I was asking if, given how faster my queries run by adding `no_found_rows => true`, that would be an issue with other queries and if it's so good, what are the down-sides of using it. Having created / worked with a complex framework within WordPress, I think most **important** questions about WordPress, given how much is given to us out the box are about architecture. I think my question would provide valuable information to anyone that's serious about making their systems run as fast, even if I'm wrong, others could chime in.

Answer (score 9):

Your code will run five SQL queries in total.

When setting `no_found_rows => true` the first two queries

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID IN (1,49,63,249,72,95,259,207,183,225) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 10

SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

will become a single query like

```sql
SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID IN (1,49,63,249,72,95,259,207,183,225) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

so yes, `no_found_rows` will improve performance to some extent.

> I don't need any meta information, no paging information, no counting of the posts, nothing, just the raw posts

In this case, you can further optimize. `WP_Query` will cache taxonomies by default, but setting `update_post_term_cache => false` will skip the following query

```sql
SELECT t.*, tt.*, tr.object_id FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category', 'post_tag', 'post_format') AND tr.object_id IN (1, 49, 63, 72, 95, 183, 207, 225, 249, 259) ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

Likewise, setting `update_post_meta_cache => false` will avoid `WP_Query` caching posts metadata and will skip the following query

```sql
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (1,49,63,72,95,183,207,225,249,259) ORDER BY meta_id ASC
```

So we can go from five (5) queries down to two (2) just setting these attributes.

Keep in mind that these optimzations can lead to N+1 problems if afterwards during the loop you actually attempt to display categorization information or any metadata such as post thumbnails, so use them wisely.

Comment: Also `'orderby' => 'ASC'` is incorrect. It should be `'order' => 'ASC'`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to try and answer:

> Is `no_found_rows => true` a must-have when querying big lists of posts where you just need to know about all the posts in a given query?

Yes, but you shouldn't be doing that anyway. Fetching large numbers of posts in a single query is bad for numerous reasons:

- memory exhaustion - all those post objects take up memory, as do the post meta and terms that get primed when they're fetched
- page generation time - all that priming and querying takes time, as does the actual display of the post and sending the output
- unexpected assumptions - "there'll only ever be 5 business posts, it's not an issue", famous last words said a year before an RSS aggregator is piped into that post type, or the business need changes, or an error duplicates every business post by accident, or a botched migration, or a site that was only meant to get minimal traffic blows up huge

If you must, e.g. in a CLI command, fetch the posts in batches of 50 in a do while loop. There are far worse things for performance that can be done, and the example in the original post is already rather fast thanks to `post__in` and no other options.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a "must have", but you should use it whenever you are not interested in knowing the total amount of post.

Default parameters are pet peeve of mine, and generally I advocate about never letting parameters default to default and instead have a conscious decision per each. This is not about performance per-se but about better control and understanding of how your code works.

Sure it will lead to very verbose function calls, but if you have a pattern that you reuse many time, you can just create a wrapper around `WP_Query` that will make the code more readable.